# Automagically create class diagram from java code in umbrello?

Tags: java, uml, umbrello

I was able to import the java code into umbrello.

However, how can I generate the class diagram automagically? Perhaps umbrello does *not* have that feature.

Answer (score 5):

From the [handbook](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdesdk/umbrello/code-import.html):

*Note that Umbrello UML Modeller will not create any kind of Diagram for showing your classes, they will only be imported into your Model so that you can use them later in any diagram you want.*

Once you've done that, it looks like you just drag and drop the items onto the class diagram and it even connects them for you.

Comment: Yup - this works great in Umbrello. Tried with C++11

Comment: Ah, you have to drag over.... meh, it still leaves a lot to be desired... :-(